# honey's dissolving/preserving flesh

Tags: meat, honey, bava-batra

Seemingly, there's an idea that honey dissolves flesh (which thereby turns into honey. I don't have a primary source for this, but there is [an ibn Ezra story about it](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D)). How does this fit in with [the *Bavli*, *Bava Basra* 3:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3266&size=1), which says that honey preserves flesh? *Dissolve* would seem to be the opposite of *preserve* in this context.

(Note: I'm not asking about what modern science says about the issue. I'm asking only about how the two Jewish-sourced statements relate to one another.)

Comment: I like the answers offered, but still wish someone had some source. I've found that the _Intziklopedya Talmudis_ discusses honey's dissolving things in it (in its article on _d'vash_), mentioning also (IIRC) breadcrumbs. It refers the reader to _Sh'elos Us'shuvos Rabenu Asher_, _k'lal_ 24 #6, _Magen Avraham_ 247:3, _Chok Yaakov_ 467:16, and _Sh'elos Us'shuvos Chasam Sofer_, _YD_ 70 and 117, none of which I've had a chance to look up yet; perhaps one of them discusses my question....

Comment: A Fig is a kosher food and yet if you google it you will find that the fig actually produces an enzyme called ficain (also known as ficin) which digests the dead wasps and the fig absorbs the nutrients to create the ripe fruits and seeds.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88203

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe indeed honey will penetrate into organic material and dissolve it, but only some distance. With a small creature like a bee, then, that's enough to include its entire body; with a human corpse, the bulk of it will still remain intact.

---

The issue is discussed in [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 84:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=375) and commentaries there. The Mechaber writes that "honey tends to preserve things immersed in it"; Shach (:37) observes that this is true only if the creature is whole, but that if it is dissected, then on the contrary the honey will dissolve it. The case at hand seems to have involved bees' legs that were in the honey (see Beur Hagra there :37), not the entire insect.

Answer (score 3):

The ibn Ezra story is about a bee (which has no flesh) dissolving into honey, the Gemara is about human flesh.

Comment: Okay, but that sort of begs the question. What's the difference, then, between humans and bees (in this context)? I'd think honey would dissolve (or preserve) both if either.

Comment: Well bees are the ones that produce honey, and maybe therefore they dissolve in it.

Comment: bees do not have flesh....  I don't understand the question.

Comment: @avi, good point. So perhaps honey dissolves [chitin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoskeleton) but preserves human skin? Conceivable, but not very plausible.

Comment: @msh210, don't forget that you didn't ask for an explanation that would stand up to modern scientific scrutiny.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, true, good point. But if the difference between the two cases in the question is that bees have an exoskeleton where humans have skin (something I suppose we can say even _chazal_ knew), then I'd want to see a source for it rather than just logical argument, as (to my mind _bimchilas k'vod'chem_) it's not very strong logic.

Comment: @msh210 I agree regarding the materials argument. Gershon's argument about bees' association with honey sounds more plausible from a pre-scientific point of view, but would also need a source.

Answer (score 1):

See Ran Avoda Zar 16b on dafi harif, after mishna.  The Gemara says if you add stuff to honey it ruins.  The Rans 2nd phsat there

Comment: Would you care to finish the sentence about the Ran's 2nd pshat?