# Was there a traditional Hebrew equivalent of a Sator Square?

Tags: history, grammar-dikduk

It seems a lot of old Latin stuff liked this [Sator Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sator_Square), five five-letter words that form a palindrome:

```
S A T O R
A R E P O
T E N E T
O P E R A
R O T A S
```

Was there ever a Hebrew equivalent to this? (I'm not asking if you can come up with one now; I'm asking if anything like this was found on Jewish carvings, in Ibn Ezra's riddles, or the like. Hopefully therefore on-topic as "Judaism.")

And no, I will not attempt to connect this to the Gemara where Moshe goes *forward* in time to R' Akiva's classroom!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88203/finding-a-source-for-a-palindrome-attributed-to-ibn-ezra

Comment: I guess "Daniel's" Mene-mene doesn't qualify. ;-)

Comment: @JoelK do I just call that an answer? Or this a duplicate question?

Comment: If you are referring to word squares in general but not limited to 5 letters, yes. There is a tradition that was taught by Rabbi Yosef Tzayach or Tetzayach that deals with this subject. There is also related material found in Sefer Pardes Rimonim by Rabbi Moshe Cordevero dealing with the 42 letter name of G-d.

Comment: @Shalom I guess that’s an answer...

Comment: The verse אֱמֶת מֵאֶרֶץ תִּצְמָח (Psalms 85:12) can be arranged as a 3x3 square that can be read in two directions if you treat אר and מח as a unit. I saw this on the front cover of an old book, but I don't remember which one. [This site](http://www.kabala.022.co.il/BRPortal/br/P102.jsp?arc=185763) attributes it to Likkutei Torah on Tehillim, but I didn't find it in the [named source](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14178&st=&pgnum=444) (maybe it's another book by the same name).

Comment: There's also the חשכ-שחנ-כנם square, referenced (but not drawn out in [Daas Zekeinim to Shemos 7:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Daat_Zkenim_on_Exodus.7.25?lang=he).

Comment: @DoubleAA How is this a duplicate? The other question is asking for a specific sator square, but this one is asking for any equivalent

Comment: @ba I tend to agree but it's probably off topic anyway so might as well point people there

Comment: @DoubleAA "probably off topic anyway" is not at all a compelling reason to close (I don't think it's off topic)

Comment: my own: ולא לאל אלו